# How to Manage Transaction In EJB3.0

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

I am using EJB3.0 with weblogic server.Below is my EJB classs.
In this class, i want to maintain transaction at method level.
so I have marked method with TransactionAttribute. But when this 
method is called then it gives an below attached error.
Notice @TransactionManagement is commented.

```
@Stateless(name = "TestSystem", mappedName = "TestSystemBean")
 @Remote(value = Test.class)
//@TransactionManagement(value=TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class AssignmentSystemBean 
{

    @Resource
    protected SessionContext sessctx = null;

    public void setSessionContext(SessionContext ctx) {
        sessctx = ctx;
    }

  @TransactionAttribute(value=TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
  public int saveAssignAddress(String username, String password, Address d, int id, String s) throws SQLException,Exception {
    sessctx.getUserTransaction ().begin ();
    return 0;
  }

}
```

[image]
So my question is , Is there any other way without making bean transaction type as BEAN,
we can use @TransactionAttribute(value=TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED).
I can not mark Bean as TransactionManagementType.BEAN

Comment: Why do you want to manage the transaction yourself? What about using `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW`? Where is the attached error you mentioned?

Comment: I can assume the error has to do with the call to UserTransaction.begin(), since a container managed transaction is already in progress

Comment: I have added the error image.

Comment: @Thomas, same exception is coming with REQUIRES_NEW also.

Comment: @Gimby, this exception is coming because EJB does not marked as 'value=TransactionManagementType.BEAN'. so there any other way without marking it as BEAN type we can also use TransactionAttribute As REQUIRED or REQUIRED_NEW

Comment: @Naveen of course you'll have to remove that `sessctx.getUserTransaction ().begin ();` if you're using `REQUIRES_NEW` (I assumed you tried that).

Comment: @naveen rather than guess away actually learn the difference between container managed transactions and bean managed transactions :/ Plenty of documentation available to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

After commenting out `@TransactionManagement(value=TransactionManagementType.BEAN)` it means that you use container managed transactions (CMT). However in method `saveAssignAddress()` you try to invoke `getUserTransaction()` which is not allowed in beans with CMT. As spec says:

> The getUserTransaction method returns the javax.transaction.UserTransaction interface. The instance can use this interface to demarcate transactions and to obtain transaction status. Only instances of a session bean with bean-managed transaction demarcation can use this method.

So you miexed two problems here. Remove `sessctx.getUserTransaction ().begin ();` because such construction should be used only with bean managed transactions (BMT).

Comment: Right. Either you use CMT (x)or BMT.

Comment: @Naveen mixed mode wouldn't be wise anyways. The question is: _why_ would you even want to do that?

Comment: @Thomas, one more thing when I marked this EJB Bean as BEAN type, then server start maintaining permanent connection with DB, and after some time start giving another exception ResourcePoolException'. I really do not where connection is open and how to track it. can you give me some direction to debug it so that i can use BEAN type mode

Comment: @Naveen I suspect you're not closing all of the transactions. Besides that I can't suggest any location to start debugging. I'd probably start somewhere in the stacktrace of that exception and look for where the connections are opened and closed. Last but not least I'd suggest not using bean managed transactions as they are more likely to be done wrong. So I repeat my question: _why_ do you want to manage the transactions yourself?

Comment: @Thomas, I was working very old project where all thing are already exist not i am doing migration activity, where i am stuck.